# Ruby each.with_index(1) returns error: no block given (yield)

Tags: ruby, cucumber, page-object-gem

Trying to iterate table rows, skipping the first row. Using Ruby, Cucumber and Page-object gem.

**PAGE_CLASS**

```
  table(:table_data, id: 'list')
```

**STEP DEFINITION**

```
@current_page.table_data_element.each.with_index(1) do |row|
  puts row.value
end
```

getting error message: `LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me.

```
   @current_page.table_data_element.each do |row|
      if row.text == ''
        next
      else
        row.link_element(text: 'Edit').visible?
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
array.drop(1).each do |row|
  ...
end
```

How does this work?

- `drop` skips `n` elements, this does not modify the original array
- `each` enumerates over all remaining elements

Comment: Method `Array` does not exist for page-object element `Table`. Therefore I can't call it.

Answer (score 1):

A clean way to do this without modifying the array would be:

```
array[1..-1].each { |row| }
```

array[1..-1] specifies a range of indexes within the array, starting at index 1 (since 0 would be the index of the first element within the array) and going through to the last index (-1).

Edit: OP has updated that the information returned isn't an array, the following syntax should work as the question intends:

```
@current_page.table_data_element.each.with_index(1) do |row, index|
  puts row.value
end
```

Comment: `drop` does not modify the original array

Comment: @akuhn I hadn't read your answer when I posted this, I wasn't stating that your answer modified the array, just stated that this solution didn't modify the array. Sorry for any confusion. Both answers work, and yours is very readable, I upvoted it! Cheers.

Comment: Cool. You raised a good point though, I should have been explicit about mutability, after there is `shift` which does mutate the receiver.

Comment: But these are useless for me, as I can't apply them in my code. `Arrays` not supported in page-object `Table` element.

Comment: @codesman in that case, since it is an enumerable you were on the right track with .with_index(1) I'll edit it to show the syntax for .with_index on enumerable objects.

Comment: @codesman did you have any issues with this answer that I can further elaborate on to help or can you mark this question as completed?

Comment: @OneNeptune Thanks for your contribution. But `.each` method in page-object gem doesn't have `.with-index()` method to apply. So, this solution didn't work for me.